# MSBUILD - Optimize ResolveProjectReferences target

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compilation, msbuild

We have a large solution of 300+ projects.

The build process is taking a long time. We have looked into combining the number of projects but management is reluctant to allocate enough time for that.

I have tried the following:

- Set copy local to false
- Use a common bin folder for the solution

However, builds still take 5+ minutes, even when there is just a small change to one small projects. Note that the incremental build process works fine, and only the projects that have changed get built.

While looking at the diagnostics, it appears that most of the time is spent in the ResolveProjectReferences target. That target appears to be calling the `<MSBuild>` task. That particular call appears to take 500 ms each time. That sounds high to me considering that nothing gets built the majority of the time! i.e. all it does is check the modified date of the assembly and conclude that nothing needs to be built.

That process seems very inefficient to me. Is there anything I can do? For instance could I create a temporary file that keeps track of all the projects that have changed since the last build and override the ResolveProjectReferences target to use that? Anything else?

Note:

- I build from the command line.
- I use the /m switch
- I only output build errors to the console

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Dude.... I thought I had unintentionally removed my first name while editing the post so I added it back..  I did not realize somebody else had removed it..

Comment: It is dominated by disk overhead, locating and opening the files to read the metadata.  Spindle disks are slow.  If you have smart management then they buy everybody an SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. we pushed for SSD but unfortunately did not get it.. I was hoping there was a software alternative... :)